# Git and submodule usage

Tags: git, version-control

So, I have the following folder structure:

```
.
└── testSubModules
    ├── README.md
    └── controllers
        ├── controller-1
        │   └── test.c
        ├── controller-10
        ├── controller-2
        ├── controller-3
        ├── controller-4
        ├── controller-5
        ├── controller-6
        ├── controller-7
        ├── controller-8
        └── controller-9
```

`testSubMoudles` is the root of my git directory. Each of the folders under the `controllers` directory represents a project in `eclipse`

I would like to have the ability to manage the project both at the root (`testSubModules`) as well at each individual project under it.

I think [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are what I'm looking for.

**Requirements/Goals/Desired work flow**

1. A new developer should be able to get the project both by the root

`git clone url/subModules`

or by individual project

`git clone url/subModules/controller-1`

From reading that tutorial, I don't think this is possible.

2. How can a developer make commits and push changes only on a submodule?

Lets say I did some work under controller-1. What would be the workflow to add my changes to that submodules

3. Lets say, Eric, another developer now wants my changes on the submodule, how can he update his work area?
4. Lets say, James, another developer wants everything, then he can do a `git pull` on the root of the project.

Maybe everything I have state is not the intended use for submodules. In that case what should I do?

Comment: // , Would you consider summarizing this in the form of a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Rakefile concept : In project you can combine multiple project :

`desc 'submodule'
task :submodule do
  sh 'git submodule init'
  sh 'git submodule update'
  sh 'git submodule add <origen>'..
..
end`


`desc 'submodulePull'
task :submodulePull do
  sh 'git submodule update'
  sh 'git submodule foreach git pull'
end`

Terminal :

> `rake submodule` to add other project in your project .
>
> cd `project` to use project independently. can run git etc..
>
> `rake submodulePull` to pull all project change .

[submodule link](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Comment: ` desc '*' `  is optional , we can use for description/comment/multi line comment .

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what submodules were intended for.

The thing is, cloning doesn't work quite the way you suggested in your question, unless you host the individual repositories in a url structure that matches the project structure, in that case you can actually clone url/ParentRepo/SubModule.  An example of this would be https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/mediawiki  and https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/mediawiki/extensions/* - each extension is in a url path that matches it's relative location as a submodule within the mediawiki directory.

Unfortunately, git repositories aren't usually hosted in this way, for example, on github your namespace is flat so you can't nest one repository underneath the url of another. When cloning the submodules individually you need to know the absolute url of the submodule's git repository, which isn't necessarily related to the url of the parent repository.

Submodules only conceptually exist inside your repository - when you do a basic clone of the parent repository, it doesn't fetch the submodules at all. To get the submodules with the parent repository, you have to do the initial clone with `git clone recursive` or, if you already have a clone without the submodules, run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to fetch them.

Another issue with submodules is that development that is done directly on the submodule repository doesn't automatically show up in the parent repository. You have to explicitly add the changes and commit them to the parent repository after pushing new commits to the submodule repository. This extra step is error prone and annoying but it's fundamental to the way submodules work.